# Icecast html 5 player with user/pass identification

Tags: icecast

I would like to embed a simple radio player on my site. The radio stream needs user/pass identification to play the stream, how is it possible to implement that into the code?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a public radio stream it makes no sense to require a username/password to play it.
You should be able to do it like this, anyway:

`<audio src="http://user:pass@server.tld/mount.ogg">`

But note that this means that every able to access the site can see the username and password, thats why I said it makes no sense to have one in first place.

Answer (score -1):

I've the same requirement. We need to user "https" url for the audio src. When i give the https url, it prompts the browser default user/pswd popup.
Let me know if you found any solution for this.

Comment: This should be comment. This block is for answer. Please delete this post